# Changing one variable in all the headers of api requests using jmeter

Tags: rest, api, jmeter

Situation:
Using recording with Jmeter I have generated a list of api requests. The way my test object works is that when you login using UI it creates a key for the entire session (which also keeps on changing), however there is an option of having a static api key for a user that you can use for all requests when sending the api requests NOT using the UI of my software.

Problem:
I have a list of api requests that I want to test but I would like to overwrite only one variable in the header of all my api requests (i.e. adding the static api key).

Is there a way of overwriting only one variable in all (most of) the headers?

[image: Visually it looks like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) lets you add or override HTTP request headers.

Create a header manager at the top and enter the common value. This value will be send with all the headers.

For more information check the below link:-
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add/Copy desired `HTTP Header Manager` above the `Thread Group` OR above `Recording Controller` and remove/disable all `HTTP Header Manager` inside request samplers, all request samplers will use the Main HTTP Header by default.

Cheers!